Expo OSM Map implementation
I want to implement a MapView into expo where I am using OSM as a source for free. The main thing I want is the display of the housenumbers on the map.
I am currenty using react-native-maps but with that I cant use google maps on IOS for free, and even if I cant really do everything i want to.

What is your question?

Is there a such a library or something with which I can implement OSM?
